# Not able to delete active directory

Tags: azure, active-directory

There was an app registered first, As suggested i clicked 'see list' and deleted the app that was there under the App Registration blade. Now it been 10 min me trying to delete this AD and when i click 'see list' nothing comes up.  Any suggestion would help.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Ok i figured it out, I was working with B2C tutorial long time ago and i needed to delete the actual application in order to deleted the AD.

I think what 'see list' shows when you try to delete the AD is just reference of the objects...you actually have to go find the object and delete it..instead of deleting what 'see list' shows. Hope that makes sense.

Maybe its a bug!
[image]